# npm not running scripts in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-scripts

The problem is that when I do `npm start` OR `npm run customScriptCommand` npm just not doing anything with the project and quickly just return new line in the terminal.

I've tried removing node and npm from my machine and then do brew installation for node and npm, but it does not fix the problem.

Then I tried removing node and npm from the brew installation and installing it again from nvm, but it also does not fix the problem.

**NPM Details**

```
npm -v -> 6.11.3
which npm -> /usr/local/bin/npm
```

**NodeJS Details**

```
node -v -> v12.12.0
which node ->/usr/local/bin/node
```

**Scripts in package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "devstart": "DEBUG=app-name:* nodemon ./bin/www", //I've changed my actual app name to "app-name"
  },
```

If I do `node ./bin/www` OR `DEBUG=app-name:* nodemon ./bin/www` it will work:

[image]

### Update

- I've tried on other project that does not have problem on my colleague's machine, with `git clone` do `npm install` and tried to run the project, but it still failed
- Even with fresh project which I just did `npm init -y` it fail,

```
{
   "name": "test"
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "index.js",
   "scripts": {
       "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
   },
   "keywords": [],
   "author": "itsme",
   "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Can you post your whole package.json? The bits you’ve shown look right.

Comment: even with new project which I just did `npm init` it still failed.

```
mkdir test
cd test && npm init -y
```

the resulted package.json:
```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "nrajan",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`npm config set ignore-scripts false` would do the trick for you.

The struggle is real my friend, not following random tutorials from now.

https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/541

Comment: thank you, funny that I did re-install the node installation several times did not encounter this variable setup.

hope that other people will be helped with this

Answer (score 1):

Installing `npm install --save-dev nodemon` and running `npm start` did the magic for me

[image]

Answer (score -3):

You can install yarn and it works; just run `yarn start`. As to what caused the problem I have no idea.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.