# laravel 6 authentication "npm run dev not working"

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm, webpack

Since laravel 6 the new way to implement authentication you have to get laravel/ui package via composer by running `composer require larvel/ui` then you have to generate the scaffolding you need here mine is bootstrap `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth` then you run `npm install` to get the node_modules and lastly you run `npm run dev` to build your assets. But the problem is when I run `npm run dev` nothing happens and I have no errors displayed in the console. When I opened the package.json file I've noticed that the `npm run dev` executes the `npm run development` command. So I tried to directly run `npm run development` and still nothing happened. The `npm run development` command consist of running this command **"cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"** So I tried to run that and it compiled all the assets. So it is working but what I don't get is why npm commands aren't working either it is  **"npm run development"** **"npm run watch"** or any other command they don't execute they just throw a new prompt with no error message.

- (node -v) v12.16.0
- (npm -v) 6.12.0
- (laravel -v) Laravel Installer 3.0.1
- (composer -v) version 1.9.0

Comment: try this npm install webpack --save-dev , then try npm run dev

Comment: hey @LalitKumar thanks for your answer I tried it but still nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58759894/npm-not-running-scripts-in-package-json) did the trick for me guys. I remember that I've once put `npm config set ignore-scripts` to `true` and that's the reason why it ignores the scripts in package.json. The solution is to change it to `false`