# How to start webpack dev server through npm?

Tags: npm, webpack

I am trying to run webpack-dev-server through npm and it is not starting. However, when I run the command directly, it is starting the dev server up correctly.

When I run `npm start` or `npm run start` (in the same folder as my package.json file), simply nothing happens (no error messages - the command just returns). When I run `webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack/webpack.config.dev.js` the server starts just fine.

I have run `npm install`. My npm version is `6.13.4` on MacOS.

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A light foundation for your next frontend project based on webpack.",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack/webpack.config.prod.js --colors",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack/webpack.config.dev.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/wbkd/webpack-starter.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "webpack",
    "startkit",
    "frontend",
    "es6",
    "javascript",
    "webdev"
  ],
  "author": "webkid.io",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/wbkd/webpack-starter/issues"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^3.0.4",
    "file-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.4",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.8.7",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful to see the complete **package.json**. So far I was unable to reproduce the problem in my own project on macOS with **npm 6.14.2**

Comment: @tromgy, I have added the entire package.json file now in the post

Comment: Just to be sure, are you running the `npm start` command in the same folder as the package.json file ?

Comment: @Seblor, yes. I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: It was an issue with my npm setup. This fixed it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59284926/844822